# Exporting SQL Server Data Files and Remounting as FileTables

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, export, filetable

We would like to move data from our local SQL Server 2008 R2 instance into a SQL Server 2012 running on Amazon EC2 (virtual machine in the AWS cloud). My first thought was to:

(a) export the data using a SQL Server command or SSIS

(b) GZIP and TAR the resulting files by table

(c) FTP up to Amazon S3 and decompress

(d) Use Amazon EC2 based SQL Server to map the files (still sitting on S3) into a FileTable.

Has anyone ever done anything like this before?  Is there a recommended way to export the original data files so that they can easily be mounted later as FileTables?

Thanks!